# How to use CSS float to create this pattern?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create this layout with pure CSS. I am having trouble with the clear left/right. I wonder if this is possible without sub-grouping?
 Thanks in advance for you answers/help.

```
<div>
    --------------------------------------------------------
    |          | [item 1] |          | [item 4] |          |
    | [item 0] |----------| [item 3] |----------| [item 6] |
    |          | [item 2] |          | [item 5] |          |
    --------------------------------------------------------
</div>
```

My code

```
<div>
    <a href="#item-0" class="biggie">[item 0]</a>
    <a href="#item-1" class="small">[item 1]</a>
    <a href="#item-2" class="small">[item 2]</a>
    <a href="#item-3" class="biggie">[item 3]</a>
    <a href="#item-4" class="small">[item 4]</a>
    <a href="#item-5" class="small">[item 5]</a>
    <a href="#item-6" class="biggie">[item 6]</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the CSS you've tried so far.

Comment: can you change that structure ??

Comment: Here's one way: (it doesn't use the clear property though)- https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QqXyoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along `flex` instead `float`, You may also use `nth-child(xn)` to avoid the use of class.

`margin:auto` can help to align and spray them evenly on the row.

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  height:3em;
}
a {
  margin:auto;
  background:gray/*see me */
}
a:nth-child(3n - 2) {
  margin:1em auto;
  background:yellow/*see me */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#item-0" >[item 0]</a>
    <a href="#item-1" >[item 1]</a>
    <a href="#item-2" >[item 2]</a>
    <a href="#item-3" >[item 3]</a>
    <a href="#item-4" >[item 4]</a>
    <a href="#item-5" >[item 5]</a>
    <a href="#item-6" >[item 6]</a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
    <a href="#item-0" >[item 0]</a>
    <a href="#item-1" >[item 1]</a>
    <a href="#item-2" >[item 2]</a>
    <a href="#item-3" >[item 3]</a>
    <a href="#item-4" >[item 4]</a>
    <a href="#item-5" >[item 5]</a>
    <a href="#item-6" >[item 6]</a>
    <a href="#item-7" >[item 7]</a>
    <a href="#item-8" >[item 8]</a>
    <a href="#item-9" >[item 9]</a>
</div>
```

Comment: After testing out various answers, G-Cyr's answer works best for my scenario. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Flexbox if you want to set fixed height on parent element.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
div > a {
  flex: 1;
}
div > a.biggie {
   flex: 0 0 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#item-0" class="biggie">[item 0]</a>
    <a href="#item-1" class="small">[item 1]</a>
    <a href="#item-2" class="small">[item 2]</a>
    <a href="#item-3" class="biggie">[item 3]</a>
    <a href="#item-4" class="small">[item 4]</a>
    <a href="#item-5" class="small">[item 5]</a>
    <a href="#item-6" class="biggie">[item 6]</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad Vracar, this is clean and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the perfect use case for CSS Grid layout:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, auto) / repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}
div > a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
div > a.biggie {
   grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#item-0" class="biggie">[item 0]</a>
    <a href="#item-1" class="small">[item 1]</a>
    <a href="#item-2" class="small">[item 2]</a>
    <a href="#item-3" class="biggie">[item 3]</a>
    <a href="#item-4" class="small">[item 4]</a>
    <a href="#item-5" class="small">[item 5]</a>
    <a href="#item-6" class="biggie">[item 6]</a>
</div>
```

You can use the Flexbox solution as a fallback for non-Grid-supporting browsers.